# 3D curved image perspective in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix, 3d, curve

I want to display an Image on a 3D sphere and I need to curve the image to fit the sphere surface.

The result I want :

[image]

(curved according the sphere)

I tried to transform the image with `Matrix4()` and rotate method but this is only doing a 'flip' action according the axis :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            //..rotateX(0.3),
            ..rotateY(0.3)
            ..rotateZ(0.2),
          child: Image.network(
            "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1369012.jpg",
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

How can we do this ?
Maybe with a plugin that I didn't found ?

Comment: you can use [vector_math](https://pub.dev/packages/vector_math) packages published by **Google developers**

Comment: could you provide an example  @YagneshLashkari

Comment: read this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-simple-3d-engine-in-flutter-cc4a7edc943e)